# how to delete image from database and image folder in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to delete image from database and also delete from folder where it save

My delete link is

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'user/delete_news/'.$row['id']."/".$row['image'];?>" class="confirm"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button></a>
```

My delete function is

```
function delete_news($id,$path)
    {


        $query = $this->db->query("DELETE FROM deleted_news WHERE id = '$id'");
       unlink(base_url().'assets/img/news_image/'.$path);

        if($query)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Please give me right solution of this problam...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will work

```
 unlink(FCPATH.'assets/img/news_image/'.$path);
```